# Keras batch normalization - what axis?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

My data is shaped like this:

```
(50000, 28, 28)
```

It is 2D images, and the first dimension is the number of samples. My first layer does flattening. I also want to add BatchNormalization layers:

```
model.add(ll.InputLayer([28, 28]))

model.add(ll.Flatten())

# network body

model.add(ll.Dense(1000, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.01), activation='elu'))
model.add(ll.BatchNormalization())
```

What is the correct value for axis to pass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually want to normalize the feature dimension over the batch so, for flat inputs, you should set `axis=-1` in `BatchNormalization`.

Comment: I see, so that's the default, i.e. I don't have to change my code.